# No such file or directory google colab

Tags: python, duplicates, google-colaboratory

```
error:
in _preread_check(self)
     82                                            "File isn't open for reading")
     83       self._read_buf = pywrap_tensorflow.CreateBufferedInputStream(
---> 84           compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512)
     85 
     86   def _prewrite_check(self):

NotFoundError: /gdrive/My Drive/object_detection/data/images/11.jpg.jpg; No such file or directory
```

but the image is present and it can be opened manually in desktop, thanks in advance

This is the code that triggered the error:

```
data_base_url = '/gdrive/My Drive/object_detection/data/'

#location of images
image_dir = data_base_url +'images/'

def split(df, group):
  data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
  gb = df.groupby(group)
  return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]

def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'r+') as fid:
      encoded_jpg = fid.read()
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you open/try to read the image?

Comment: def create_tf_example(group, path):
     22         with tf.io.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'r+') as fid:
---> 23           encoded_jpg = fid.read()
     24         encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
     25         image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/lib/io/file_io.py in read(self, n)
    120       string if in string (regular) mode.
    121     """
--> 122     self._preread_check()
    123     if n == -1:
    124       length = self.size() - self.tell()

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/detailed-tutorial-build-your-custom-real-time-object-detector-5ade1017fd2d

in this , section 6- genrating trf record

Comment: EDIT your original post with the code, do not put it in the comments. There is very little formatting in the comments

Comment: can u please check now

Answer (score 0):

```
NotFoundError: /gdrive/My Drive/object_detection/data/images/11.jpg.jpg; No such file or directory
```

I see that you are trying to get 11.jpg.jpg , correcting this to the right extension might help.

You might want to print the files in the folder using python to see how the file paths are printed and check against how you call them.

Answer (score 0):

It's because while creating test and train label csv, the column 'filename' is adding extra .jpg into the filename. Check your image file name, it already might have .jpg in the file name.

In the function xml_to_csv(), the author's code is

'''

```
value = (root.find('filename').text + '.jpg',
               int(root.find('size')[0].text),
               int(root.find('size')[1].text),
               member[0].text,...
```

'''

Remove .jpg from the file extension. This will solve the issue